# Executing CMD long commands via Java

Tags: java, cmd, environment-variables

I'm working on executing cmd commands via Java and i got this piece of code which is working fine for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Exec {
   public static void main(String args[]){
       try {
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start notepad.exe");
          System.out.println("Command Executed!");
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Now this snippet just starts notepad.exe, but i want to execute some commands including paths etc for example

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c c:/Users/Subhan/Desktop index.htm");
```

In this case it does nothing. It doesn't even throws any kind of exception.

So how to do that? And i'm just looking forward to set up environmental variables through some cmd command is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried `cmd /c c:/Users/Subhan/Desktop index.htm` alone, I mean in your cmd.exe? Does it work?

Comment: In my cmd i cd to the desktop dir and then write index.htm and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple you have to invert the slash "/" to back slash "\"

Try "cmd /cd c:\Users\Subhan\Desktop index.html"

also have a look at this. This work! Good luck!
C:
cd \Windows
start notepad.exe
cd "\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe
cd "\Program Files\Skype\Phone"
start Skype.exe
exit

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /cd c:/Users/Subhan/Desktop index.html");

this doesn't worked for me while the one you gave me above gives a syntax error. I just inverted '\' to '/' then it worked.